# Fragment refreshing on backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity `MainActivity` there are three fragments associated with this activity.

Now one of my fragment `Timeline` has a listview. Which I populate from a Database in the backend. I use an AsyncTask to fetch values from the DB and process them to the List. I trigger this AsyncTask in the onCreate of the Fragment `Timeline`.

Now from `Timeline` on click of any list item I navigate to a different `Activity` called as `DetailActivity`

The problem is whenever I press back from the `DetailActivity` the onCreate of my `MainActivity` is called and my list refreshes again - the whole DB operation is called again and my list does not retain its state.

I am calculating the visible items of my List before I navigate away from the Fragment but I am forced to use static values for these variables so that I retain the position. How to avoid this?

Below are the snippets of my onPause and onResume as laid down in the fragment `Timeline`

```
    static  int index;
    static int top;
    @Override
    public void onPause(){

        System.out.println("onPause");
        index = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }


@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume(); 
        //dbHelper.open();
        System.out.println("onResumr");
        lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setTitle("Timeline"); 
        uiHelper.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity());
        updateUI();

    }
```

This also forces my AsyncTask to run again and again, which is an overhead.

#### Edit:

The root of this problem - After struggling for so many days I borrowed a friends phone to test and all was sorted on this new phone. I found out that I had turned on the `Do not keep Activities` option in my Developer Settings. The Dumb me!!

Comment: Show your `MainActivity` code and how it creates / manages the `Fragment`.

Comment: The code is too long to post here! I will still try and skim through the relevant LOC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, the default behavior of the `Fragment` class. A `Fragment` is *destroyed* whenever the containing `Activity` is *paused*, and *recreated* whenever the containing `Activity` is *resumed*. If you use an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment` for the list, you would not experience the same behavior. With an `Activity`:

- `AsyncTask`s and/or web services would not be called again.
- The list would show the previously scrolled position.

If you want the same behavior with a `Fragment`, you need to override the `onSaveInstanceState()` method. And while interesting, it is not a small amount of work.

**EDIT:**

Make sure the `Do not keep Activities` option is unselected in your phone's Developer Settings. This, though, does not change the essential behavior of the `Fragment` class that I have outlined above.

Comment: Agreed, for now I have 30 minutes to launch and I will stick to my static variables!

Comment: There you go Dudette :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit : Do you have documented evidence of this - I can't find anything. An `Activity` can be paused by the appearance of a dialog (for example) and the `Activity` remains partially visible complete with any `Fragment` attached to it. When the dialog disappears the `Activity` is resumed and I can't see any indication in my apps which suggest the `Fragments` have been destroyed / recreated.

Comment: While I am looking for some links I can tote as "documented, peer-reviewed evidence", I can point out that the OP's question is, indeed, evidence of this very behavior, and its something I've seen while using `Fragment`s. The same UI when implemented with `Activity`s shows the behavior I have described: web services / asynctasks are not called again, and the listview scroll position is automatically maintained on backpress. You can verify this behavior yourself with a list-detail flow - first with `Fragment`s and then with `Activity`s

Comment: The root of this problem - After struggling for so many days I borrowed a friends phone to test and all was sorted on this new phone. I found out that I had turned on the `Do not keep Activities` option in my Developer Settings. The Dumb me!!

Comment: @Skynet: I see, good for you ... I shall edit my answer, but I still request you to mark it as correct, because the answer is not wrong :)

Comment: Sure go ahead and add that as an Edit without removing the previous part - so that anyone who drops here has both the options to consider.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setRetainInstance(true)` on your fragment. The lifecycle will be slightly different though.

A nice view of a fragment's lifecycle is available here
http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html

Comment: `setRetainInstance(true)` works for *configuration changes*, like rotation and `ViewPager` swipes. Will `setRetainInstance(true)` work even if the user navigates away from the `Activity` ?

Comment: Nope - I had tried this before posting the question!